# What does it mean by "segment variables matched by the URL pattern" in the following?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, endpoint, semantics, asp.net-core-middleware

Reading the book **Pro ASP.NET Core 3, by Adam Free Man**, I saw some lines saying as follow:

> The endpoint in Listing 13-7 enumerates the `HttpRequest.RouteValues` property to generate
> a response that lists the names and value of the segment variables **matched by** the URL pattern.

I got confused with the highlighted part above. Could anyone explain about the following part:

> the names and value of the segment variables matched by the URL pattern.

Here is the full text I mentioned in above:

> ````
>     endpoints.MapGet("{first}/{second}/{third}", async context => {
>         foreach (var kvp in context.Request.RouteValues) {
>             await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}\n");
>         } } ```
> ````

> The RouteValuesDictionary class is enumerable, which means that it can
> be used in a foreach loop to generate a sequence  of
> KeyValuePair<string, object> objects, each of which corresponds to the
> name of a segment variable and the corresponding  value extracted from
> the request URL. The endpoint in Listing 13-7 enumerates the
> `HttpRequest.RouteValues` property to generate a response that lists
> the **names and value of the segment variables matched by the URL**
> **pattern**. The names of the segment variables are first, second, and
> third, and you can see the values extracted from the URL by
> restarting ASP.NET Core and requesting any three-segment URL, such as
> http://localhost:5000/apples/oranges/cherries,  which produces the
> response shown in Figure 13-8.

Answer (score 0):

The string `"{first}/{second}/{third}"` is a URL pattern(route template)  which is used to configure how the endpoint is matched.

In your case,`"{first}/{second}/{third}"`would match url like

```
https://localhost:7192/a/b/c

https://localhost:7192/1/2/3
```

but the url like

```
https://localhost:7192/a/b/c/d
   https://localhost:7192/a/b
```

won't match

And the first segment of url path `a`would be bound to the `{first}` parameter,`b` would be bound to `{second}` and so on.all of them would be stored in `HttpRequest.RouteValues` in a key value format:

```
first:a,
second :b,
thrid :c
```

The official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#endpoints) related